# Connecting to Oracle with 32 bit apps running on Vista 64 bit

Tags: oracle, 32-bit, vista64

I am attempting to use a 32 bit application to talk to an Oracle database from Vista 64 bit ([Embarcadero RapidSQL](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rapid_sql/index.php)). I already have the Oracle 11g 64 bit client installed for the web apps I develop, but because RapidSQL is a 32 bit application, it requires a 32 bit version of the Oracle client.

Is it safe to simply install the 32 bit Oracle client libraries in addition to the 64 bit ones, and if so are there any tips, tricks or gotchas I should be wary of when doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you install them in a different ORACLE_HOME, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, that worked much more seamlessly than I expected. No mucking around with ORACLE_HOME paths or anything, yet my Win32 app now works, and my ASP.NET apps are still executing successfully using 64 bit worker processes. :-D